# Filtered cell's how to sorted by time with formula or maybe with script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I try to sort by time "joined" cell's with query
how can i do that if i alredy use IFERROR, FILTER, and also TEXT
i try to add query before and after the {
but i couldn't get it to work

this is the formula I would like to query to be able to sort by time in B29:E29

={IFERROR(filter(A1&" "&B2&" "&text(A3:A27;"hh:mm")&" - "&B3:B27;B3:B27<>"");V1:V2);IFERROR(filter(A1&" "&D2&" "&text(A3:A27;"hh:mm")&" - "&D3:D27;D3:D27<>"");V1:V2)}

I made a sheet that shows more than if I had taken pictures
[sheet name: unsolved - sort by time](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FX_07F1Qu31FW1QOvzFMj4O_fjwilt_pX_Tw9_mFsEw/edit#gid=2095369889)

if it would be impossible to solve with a formula, I wonder if it could be done with a script

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change slightly the place of KG and UP

```
=sort({IFERROR(filter(A1&" "&TEXT(A3:A27;"hh:mm")&" "&B2&" - "&B3:B27;B3:B27<>"");V1:V2);IFERROR(filter(A1&" "&TEXT(A3:A27;"hh:mm")&" "&D2&" - "&D3:D27;D3:D27<>"");V1:V2)})
```

see in B42